# Is there an easy way to reorder the coordinate levels in a DataArray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have the following DataArray.

```
data = xr.DataArray(
    np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4),
    dims=['x', 'y', 'z'],
    coords={
        'x': ['a', 'b'],
        'y': [10, 20, 30],
        'z': [100, 200, 300, 400]
    }
)
transposed_data = data.transpose('z', 'y', 'x')
```

When I print `transposed_data`, I get coordinates:

```
>>> print(transposed_data)
...
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) int64 10 20 30
  * z        (z) int64 100 200 300 400
```

that is, the coordinates are still in the order x, y, z. I would like to reorder them to be z, y, x (matching the dimension order). Specifically, I want to see

```
>>> print(transposed_data)
...
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) int64 100 200 300 400
  * y        (y) int64 10 20 30
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: it should work with the `transpose_coords = True` kwarg (see [this discussion](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1856), but interestingly, it does not...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, everything works properly. Dataarray have changed, the coordinated (you printed above) are still the same.

To be more specific, initial dataset is

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 3, z: 4)>
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
    [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

   [[12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) int32 10 20 30
  * z        (z) int32 100 200 300 400
```

The transposed one is

```
<xarray.DataArray (z: 4, y: 3, x: 2)>
array([[[ 0, 12],
    [ 4, 16],
    [ 8, 20]],

   [[ 1, 13],
    [ 5, 17],
    [ 9, 21]],

   [[ 2, 14],
    [ 6, 18],
    [10, 22]],

   [[ 3, 15],
    [ 7, 19],
    [11, 23]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) int32 10 20 30
  * z        (z) int32 100 200 300 400
```